# Class Diagram design issue: 1 to n and 1 to 1

Tags: uml, class-design, class-diagram

Supose I have a shop in which the customer can *try* many products but finally *buys* just one. So when he '*tries*' products relation between costumer - product is 1 to n, but when he '*buys*' it's 1 to 1. How to resolve that in an UML class diagram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two associations "tries" to-n and "buys" to-1. Another option would be an association "products" to-n with a constraint which checks that the products are not bought or it is just one.

Still, an application where only one product can be bought is quite strange ;-p

Comment: Think about buying a house or a car...:)

Comment: Who said I cannot buy more than one car/house/bus/learjet? :D

Comment: Ok, savinos, let's say.. buying your own coffin...?

Answer (score 0):

1 to n seems more appropriate here because I suppose it is possible for a customer to buy more than 1 product.

If he can't buy more than one product and you don't want to keep trace of the tried products, then 1 to 1 is ok...